# Bing Map for Windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, authentication, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I need to implement a bing map in my Windows Phone 8.1 app coded using C# on Visual Studio 2015.

My question is for authentication of the bing map, can I use a key retrieved from the Bing Maps Portal (https://www.bingmapsportal.com/) or will I have to register in the Windows Dev Center (https://dev.windows.com/overview) which in return will cost me and use a key from there.
I have a DreamSpark account if that would help in any way.

I'm posting this because I searched everywhere on the net and within stackoverflow but couldn't find a proper answer to this.

If anyone is aware of this please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Use Bingmapsportal.com

Comment: Don't use the Bing maps portal for WP8.1 apps. WP8.1 doesn't use Bing Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maps in Windows Phone 8.1 are not Bing Maps, so you can't use a Bing Maps key. For WP8.1 you have to get a Map service token from the Windows dev center. The map service token has the same free limits as Bing Maps keys, and unless you have a lot of traffic or you are building an internal app (which always requires a license), it shouldn't cost you anything.

Answer (score 0):

@rbrundritt Thank you so much for resolving my uncertainty! I managed to get a Map service token from the Windows Dev Center by registering to it using a promo code taken from DreamSpark.