# Is there any Map usage limit if we use Map Service Token from developer account?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I searched lot on web, but didn't find any documentation that says about the usage limitation for MapControl in Windows Phone 8.1 App,
From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126696/bing-map-for-windows-phone-8-1-app/36565330#36565330) link I found that MapControl for WP 8.1 uses HERE maps instead of Bing Maps and only we can use MapServiceToken provided from Developer account and not from Bing Portal.
So is there any usage limit?

Answer (score 0):

It's all Bing Maps. HERE is the data provider for Bing Maps. All Windows apps using the Maps API that is in the Windows/Windows Phone SDK's along with the Bing Maps WPF and Windows 8 control, have a limit of 50,000 transactions per 24 hour period for public apps.

Note, if you really wanted to use HERE maps free terms of use instead which really isn't an option, but if you could, their limit is only 25,000, so you would actually have less transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the info, So what if I need to exceed 50,000 transactions limit, can I use Enterprise Key from Bingmaps portal? Right now I am using key that is genearated from developer account.

Comment: Yes. you will want to create a UWP Bing Maps key. You will notice that it is much longer than a standard Bing Maps key. You can parse out the application ID and token from it as a UWP key concatenates these with a standard Bing Maps key. All Bing Maps services understand this UWP key, however the WP8.1 map control hasn't been updated.

Comment: I need to exceed 50,000 transaction for my WP 8.1, so what should I do for that?

Comment: Contact the licensing team using the request a quote form here: https://www.microsoft.com/maps/